# Auto sync using Sync adapter not working on android pie & mi devices

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have use sync adapter for data synchronization and make code for periodic sync in 5 minutes interval but onPerformSync() method not called in this interval on android os version 8 & 9 & mi devices. also i have test same code in marshmallow device and it working fine in marshmallow.

i have manually enable auto-sync from settings. then try to check auto-sync is working or not.

```
 public void setSyncPeriodic(String authority, long interval_in_minute,
                                long seconds_per_minute, long milliseconds_per_second) {
        Account account = mUser.getAccount();
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        this.setAutoSync(authority, true);

        ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, authority, 1);
        final long sync_interval = interval_in_minute * seconds_per_minute
                * milliseconds_per_second;
        int flexTime = (int) (sync_interval/3);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // we can enable inexact timers in our periodic sync
            SyncRequest request = new SyncRequest.Builder()
                    .syncPeriodic(sync_interval, flexTime)
                    .setSyncAdapter(account, authority)
                    .setExtras(new Bundle()).build();
            ContentResolver.requestSync(request);
        } else {
            ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, authority, new Bundle(), sync_interval);
        }
        /*ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, authority, extras,
                sync_interval);*/

    }
```

please guild me how to implement auto-sync using sync adapter for all device & all android os version.